# How to convert binary to image in WinRT app?

Tags: wpf, image, windows-runtime

i have sample code (WPF) that convert my binary data to image(png, jpg, jpeg):

```
BitmapFrame imgSrc1;
BitmapFrame imgSrc2;
BitmapFrame imgSrc3;
imgSrc1 = new JpegBitmapDecoder(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None).Frames[0];
imgSrc2 = new JpegBitmapDecoder(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None).Frames[0];
imgSrc3 = new PngBitmapDecoder(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None).Frames[0];
```

Some troubles with classes in WinRT, there aren't classes like JpegBitmapDecoder.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a jpg decoder like this:

```
// using Windows.Graphics.Imaging
BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(BitmapDecoder.JpegDecoderId, stream)
```